# Let admin create price offers/quotes for customers in Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

Does anyone know of a plugin (or coming functionality in Commerce 3 or 4) that allows admin to create price offers/quotes for a customer and then send it to the customer's email for review?

#### Scenario

I am talking to a customer on the phone. He wants a price on a specific product/configuration. I add the desired products to the customer's basket, save it as a price offer/quote. I am allowed to adjust prices. I send the quote to the user. The user can access the quote and easily accept or reject it.

#### Feature request

I added this as a feature request here: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/1156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise raising this as a feature request on Github (i.e. issue).

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues

Commerce 3 has back end order entry (i.e. admins can enter orders on behalf of customers), but extending this to quotes etc. would be super useful and that would be  a good place to get the conversation happening.

Comment: Added feature request here: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/1156